# how do I use "this" on an component function in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to call `this.getFact` from the `Animal` component, but using `this` raises `TypeError: this is undefined`

```js
import './App.css';
import React from 'react';

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      fact: '',
    }
  }

  getFact(endpoint) {
    fetch(endpoint)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
        this.setState({
          fact: data.text,
        });
      })
  }

  Animal(props) {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>{props.name}</h1>
        <button onClick={() => this.getFact(props.endpoint)}>get a {props.name.toLowerCase()} fact</button>
      </div>
    )
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <div>
          <p>{this.state.fact}</p>
        </div>
        <div className="animals">
          <this.Animal name="Dog" endpoint="https://some-random-api.ml/facts/dog" />
          <this.Animal name="Cat" endpoint="https://some-random-api.ml/facts/dog" />
          <this.Animal name="Bird" endpoint="https://some-random-api.ml/facts/dog" />
          <this.Animal name="Otter" endpoint="https://some-random-api.ml/facts/dog" />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: You don't have an `Animal` component. You have an `Animal` method on your `App` component. Create a new component with its own methods (or create a new functional component with hooks).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to bind both of the functions (getFact and Animal) to be able to use this inside the Animal function. In your constructor do this:

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      fact: ""
    };

    // Here you will bind the functions so they can be callable with this
    this.getFact = this.getFact.bind(this);
    this.Animal = this.Animal.bind(this);
  }
```

That will solve the issue but I will suggest to move the Animal component outside of your class and pass the getFact as a prop. you still need to bind the getFact function, but honestly it will be more react like and in the long run is more maintainable. Something like this

```
function Animal(props) {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{props.name}</h1>
      <button onClick={() => props.getFact(props.endpoint)}>
        get a {props.name.toLowerCase()} fact
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}

class AppReactWay extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      fact: ""
    };
    this.getFact = this.getFact.bind(this);
  }

// Same code as you have

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <div>
          <p>{this.state.fact}</p>
        </div>
        <div className="animals">
          <Animal
            name="Dog"
            getFact={this.getFact}
            endpoint="https://some-random-api.ml/facts/dog"
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Also after checking the API response you need to modify the getFact function, is not data.text, it is data.fact.

```
  getFact(endpoint) {
    fetch(endpoint)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then(({ fact }) => {
        this.setState({
          fact
        });
      });
  }
```

Here's a working [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vigilant-elion-h1nc0?file=/src/AppReactWay.js:442-619) with both examples.

Answer (score 0):

The better approach would be to directly call `{this.Animal({ name: 'Dog', endpoint: 'https://some-random-api.ml/facts/dog'})}` and so on for every animal.

The best approach would be for `Animal` to have it's own component and pass `getFact` function as param, don't forget you will need to bind it in that case or it will loose this context.